# Asynchronous vs. Synchronous socket server for real-time application

Tags: c#, asynchronous, real-time

I am currently developing a C# socket server that needs to send and receive commands to a real-time process. The client is an android device. Currently the real-time requirements are "soft", however in the future more strict timing requirements might arise. Lets say in the future it might be to send commands to a crane that could be potentially dangerous.

The server is working, and seemingly very well with my current synchronous socket server design. I have separate threads for receiving and sending data. I am wondering if there would be any reason to attempt an asynchronous server socket approach? Could it provide more stability and/or faster performance?

Comment: async design would only be beneficail IF you you have more than one client and/or multiple messages/connections in parallel to handle... in those cases async design makes your server much better scalable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll gloss over the definition of real time and say that asynchronous sockets won't make the body of the request process any faster, but will increase concurrency (the number of requests you can take at any one time).  If all processors are busy processing something, you won't get any gain.  This only gives you gain in the situation where a processor would have sat waiting for a socket to receive something.

Just a note on real time, if your real time requirements are anything like the need to guarantee a response in x-time, then C# and .NET will not give you such guarantees.  This, however, depends on your current and future definitions of "soft".  It may be the case that you *happen* to be getting good response times, but don't confuse that with true real time systems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Adam! I guess I was getting confused by all the posts about async sockets servers being faster but now I know in what situations they are. And I completely agree on your note, C# is not a good choice for real time requirements. I am probably going to do a server in C instead if it comes to harder reqs. Another thing, are TCP sockets ever a viable option for real-time communication, or should I consider something else?

Comment: If you are doing synchronous C in comparison to asynchronous C#, you are doing yourself a big misfavor imo.

Comment: Any sort of communication across a latent medium (ie network) is not going to be brilliant for real-time systems.  TCP is a good enough choice though if you want reliability.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doubting the usefullness of something asynchronous in your aplications then you should definitely read about [this](http://martinfowler.com/articles/lmax.html). It gives you a clear idea of what the asynchronous solutions could add to your applications

Comment: http://disruptor.googlecode.com/files/Disruptor-1.0.pdf - that's the paper you should read, not Fowler's cut-copy-n-paste simplification ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are going to get more stability or faster performance.  If it really is a "real-time" system, then it should be synchronous.  If you can tolerate "near real-time" and there are long running or expensive compute operations, then you could consider an asynchronous approach.  I would not add the complexity if not needed though.

Answer (score 0):

If it's real time, then you absolutely want your communications to be backed by a queue so that you can prove temporal logic on that queue. This is what nio/io-completion-ports/async gives you. If you are using synchronous programming then you are wasting your CPU while copying data from RAM to the network card.

Furthermore, it means that your server is absolutely single-threaded. You may have a single thread even with async, but still be able to serve thousands of requests.

Say for example that a client wanted to perform a DOS attack. He would connect and send one byte of data. Your application would now become unable to receive further commands for the timeout of that connection, which could be quite large. With async, you would ACK the SYN package back, but your code would not be waiting for the full transmission.

Comment: He's using UDP.  ACK attacks don't apply.  Your advice doesn't strengthen the real-time nature of his application; it improves CPU performance and network security.  Being able to write in terms of temporal logic on an asynchronous message queue is only practical if you then have the latitude to manipulate the contents of the queue to 'catch up' if your service rate is falling behind; and it introduces pseudorandom fluctuation in the service rate that a synchronous solution could avoid (although, this is only really relevant if the link to the 'crane' is totally dedicated/predictably latent).

Comment: Where does he say he's using UDP? I can't find a mention of that. I'm not sure I disagree with you, but using async instead of sync sockets, given more than one connection, will decrease latency and that is the killer across the internet - and the internet doesn't send predictably latent packages to your process -- so I don't see how what you are talking about applies. Also, what does it matter if there's fluctuation - and what does that mean? - guessing here -- packages may arrive out of order and arbitrarily delayed anyway.

Comment: You're right that he doesn't mention UDP.  I don't know why I assumed that, maybe the reference to an industrial app (crane) put it in my head.

Comment: (cont'd) He also doesn't say he's on the internet, which I hope he isn't if he ever wants predictable arrival times.  All I really wanted to say was that it doesn't sound like going with an asynchronous server architecture is going to offer anything to his app.  ...actually, Android implies wireless, which is even worse.  I don't think he can really get any kind of real-time assurances anyway.